# geometryFlipped and renderInContext

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a subclass of UILabel that sets

```
self.layer.geometryFlipped = YES;
```

If I add this label as a subview to a view everything works as expected. But if I try to convert this view to an image the label is not visible/present in the result image.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
posterImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If before adding a label to the view I set label.geometryFlipped = NO then label appears (all letters except for the first one are upside down).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If I flip the rendering contents then all the other labels and images I have in the view will be upside down. I tried that but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the label in question...

Comment: Then render two contexts and composite the images.